# Passing Model and extra parameters from View to Controller Razor MVC3

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, web

I have a view in which I have a form with several fields, which is my View model. I would like to make a list of links (for a pager) with which when I click a certain page it would send the input data in the form + a page. I have the following javascript code, which I bind to the page links as an OnClick action:

```
function SearchCriteria() {
    this.OrderNumber = "";
    this.CustomerNumber = "";
    this.FirstName = "";
    this.LastName = "";
    this.Login = "";
    this.Company = "";
    this.Country = "";

}

function sendModel(page) {

    var myModel = new SearchCriteria();

    var PostData = JSON.stringify(myModel);
    $.post('@Url.Action("ShowCustomers","Home")', PostData);

}
```

The problem is that when I click one of the page numbers - nothing happens. As if the script isn't called.

Code to bind the function to the links:

```
<a class="@(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "current" : "")" onclick="sendModel(@i)" href="#">@(innerContent ?? i.ToString())</a>
```

This binding code is in a loop for each page, so "i" corresponds to the page for which the link is created.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to generate the links, or the HTML produced for the links and the jQuery code you are using to bind the click event to the links? The problem might be in the binding.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta, I have updated the question with the information you wanted :)

Comment: Is the `sendModel()` method in a .cshtml file or .js file?

Comment: It's defined in the same file as where it is being set as an onClick action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it, the values are being POSTed to the `ShowCustomers` action method, but are not doing anything with what the returned values.

If `ShowCustomers()` is returning either JSON or HTML, then you need to display these information:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ShowCustomers","Home")', PostData,
      function(data)
      {
        $('#results') = data;
      });
```

Comment: Well, the action method returns just a view, without any data, what am I supposed to do then? (The table displaying is handled by the server)

Comment: If it is returning only the results, then simply replace the section of the page that currently shows the results with the returned results (basically the code that I have). Otherwise, if it is returning the entire page, then I would recommend that you do not use the ajax approach and instead use javascript to create a link that has all the parameters and simply redirect the user to that page.